# How to use a CSV summary with R

Tags: r, csv

This one has been plaguing me from yesterday to this night (I've been dreaming about it ...).

Quite simple.

If I run the following command line with R:

```
tree=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3)

treetab=table(tree)

treetab
```

I have the following results:

```
1 2 3

3 2 4
```

Issue now is the following , I have a CSV file , which is already like the results above e.g

```
1 2 3

3 2 4
```

I've tried to break it into two variables and concatenate them again but to no avail ... (see below for my command lines)

```
tree=c(1,2,3)

cnt=c(3,2,4)

dara=append(as.data.frame(tree),as.data.frame(cnt))

dara1=as.data.frame(dara)
```

I'm not sure what I'm asking can be done and so far, I've checked stackerxchange, parse the web but did not find anything satisfying.

If you have any ideas, they would be gladly welcomed.

The aim, is to to be able to run the following command line :

```
table(dara)
```

And have the following results :

```
1 2 3

3 2 4
```

Thank you in advance for any leads or inputs.

Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSV file:

```
text <- "1 2 3

3 2 4"
```

Read the file and convert it into a matrix:

```
dat <- unname(as.matrix(read.table(text = text)))
```

Recontruct the `dara` object:

```
dara <- rep(dat[1, ], dat[2, ])
```

Test:

```
dara
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3

table(dara)
# dara
# 1 2 3 
# 3 2 4
```

Comment: You rock, Sven ! Many thanks on this one. I could not have done it on my own.

Answer (score 1):

```
dara <- rep(tree, cnt)
table(dara)
```